# Can you turn a popup into a regular buffer?

Tags: buffers, popup

I have a popup / floating window open which is normally used for temporary jobs, like searching the code or opening a quick REPL. Is it possible to turn that into a regular buffer? While I have it open, it does not show up in `:buffers`, so I can't just [move it to another tab](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Move_current_window_between_tabs) or open a split above the popup; it remains in the centre of my screen. In fact, if I move away using `<C-W><C-J>` or similar, I can't even move back using the opposite direction, and have to find and plug in a mouse to get back into the popup!

My particular use-case is to [keep the search results from fzf.vim's Rg command](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/808) so that I can return to them after browsing some matches. However, this should apply equally well to any other uses of floating windows / popups.

I see that [vim-floaterm](https://github.com/voldikss/vim-floaterm) allows you to store and then return to floating terminal buffers, with some hackery searching by index for buffers, but I don't fully understand why this logic is correct or necessary:

```
" find **one** visible floaterm window
function! floaterm#window#find() abort
  let found_winnr = 0
  for winnr in range(1, winnr('$'))
    if getbufvar(winbufnr(winnr), '&filetype') ==# 'floaterm'
      let found_winnr = winnr
      break
    endif
  endfor
  return found_winnr
endfunction
```

Can anyone explain the use of `winbufnr`, and how to use this to move a popup, or implement generalized store / load behaviour of popups?

Comment: `:h popup-buffer` ... popups are very specialized and restricted buffers. While you might be able to bend them into submission it'll only be by chance not by design.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hack, but if you can get the window ID of the popup (`popup_create` returns it; `popup_locate` or `popup_list` might help find it), you can get the buffer contents and create a new one:

```
const popup_winid = …
const popup_bufnr = winbufnr(popup_winid)
const lines = getbufline(popup_bufnr, 1, '$')
" do something with them, like:
new
put =lines
1delete
```